Problemas con formulas de Power Apps
he estado teniendo problemas con esta formula de Power Apps, es para hacer un cuestionario con SharePoint he estado siguiendo un tutorial
sin embargo, parece dar un error de sintaxis
ClearCollect(
colQuestions,
ShowColumns(
AddColumns(
Questions,
"Title", Title,
"Answers", Table(
{Answer: Option1},
{Answer: Option2},
{Answer: Option3},
{Answer: Option4}
)
),
"Title", "Answers"
)
)
No se cual es el error en si. Si alguien conoce la solución o que puedo estar haciendo mal, se lo agradecería mucho
imagen donde  se visualiza el error 

En PowerApps, arriba a la derecha tienes un botón que te muestra el error y te da una breve explicación de lo que ocurre. Copia el mensaje de error que te muestra y pégalo por aquí.
